# How to access a default access method using interop in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I'm doing the following on a Clojure REPL:

```
user=> (ns clojure.lang)
nil
clojure.lang=> (def tran (clojure.lang.LockingTransaction.))
#'clojure.lang/tran
clojure.lang=> (.getReadPoint tran)
```

This gives the following result:

```
IllegalArgumentException No matching field found: getReadPoint for class clojure.lang.LockingTransaction  clojure.lang.Reflector.getInstanceField (Reflector.java:271)
```

Now this method [does exist](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LockingTransaction.java#L76).

Now I think I should be able to access default access methods from the REPL.

My question is: **How to access a default access method using interop in Clojure?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but it requires some dirty tricks.

There's a weird library, [`vinyasa`](https://github.com/zcaudate/vinyasa#reflection), which makes these tricks much easier to pull.

Here's a transcript from a repl session using this odd library:

```
user=> (require '[vinyasa.inject :as inject])
nil
user=> (inject/in clojure.core [vinyasa.reflection .> .? .* .% .%> .& .>ns .>var])
[]
user=> (def locking-transaction (clojure.lang.LockingTransaction.))
#'user/locking-transaction
user=> (def get-read-point (.? clojure.lang.LockingTransaction "getReadPoint"))
#'user/get-read-point
user=> get-read-point
(#[getReadPoint :: (clojure.lang.LockingTransaction) -> void])
user=> ((first get-read-point) locking-transaction)
nil
```

Here we load up `vinyasa`, and as recommended by the library, inject its oddly named macros into `clojure.core`. Using the `.?` macro we find the protected method which the vm would usually prevent us from accessing, and via reflection get a version which can be used to circumvent the VM's security. Finally we access and call the method on our `LockingTransaction` object, and get the expected return value (`nil`).

Be aware that inserting symbols into other namespaces at runtime is not considered normal or desirable behavior in Clojure, nor is bypassing VM protections, and you can easily segfault the VM or cause very weird bugs by calling protected or private methods via reflection.

Comment: ">the vm would usually prevent us from accessing" ...
if you're in the same namespace - can't you access a default access field?

Comment: Thanks - Chris Zheng is a legendary Clojure programmer.

Comment: @hawkeye namespaces are not identical to packages

Comment: @noisesmith - I don't think it's THAT weird =)