# Why aren't namespaces the same as Java packages for interop access?

Tags: java, clojure, namespaces, package, clojure-java-interop

I'm doing the following on a Clojure REPL:

```
user=> (ns clojure.lang)
nil
clojure.lang=> (def tran (clojure.lang.LockingTransaction.))
#'clojure.lang/tran
clojure.lang=> (.getReadPoint tran)
```

This gives the following result:

```
IllegalArgumentException No matching field found: getReadPoint for class clojure.lang.LockingTransaction  clojure.lang.Reflector.getInstanceField (Reflector.java:271)
```

Now this method [does exist](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LockingTransaction.java#L76).

Now I think I should be able to access default access methods from the REPL.

I'm reliably informed that Clojure namespaces are not the same as Java packages. (ie the way to solve this problem is via reflection - for something that wouldn't require reflection in Java).

Why aren't namespaces in Clojure the same as Java packages for interop access?

Comment: I think default access needs the two classes to also be loaded from the same classloader so even if you get your expression to be evaluated in the correct package it should not work.

Comment: Thanks @cgrand could you expand on that?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the question. The way it's worded, it sounds as if you're saying, in effect, "I know that namespaces aren't the same as classes, but I think they should be the same I want to do a Java interop-style call on a namespace; why aren't they?" That can't be what you're asking, though, because in that case, unless you provide an argument, the answer would be "Why *should* they be the same in that case?" Isn't the real question: Why can't I access this Java method?  Noisesmith's [answer to your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32547544/1455243) didn't answer *that*.

Comment: I have no idea why `getReadPoint` isn't accessible, but it's not about the namespace.  You can get the same error without the `ns` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes classes aren't namespaces

```
boot.user=> (in-ns java.util.Date)
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Symbol
```

But the error you're getting isn't because the field doesn't exist, it's because it hasn't been initialized correctly. It's a Clojure concurrency primitive that requires instantiation with a java.util.concurrent.Callable and that is a pain to implement just look at the end of the class for the [testing example](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LockingTransaction.java#L76).

When initialized correctly java classes return meaningful output:

```
boot.user=> (.getTime (java.util.Date.))
1445587895021
```

or

```lisp
boot.user=> (def concurrent-queue (java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue.))
#'boot.user/concurrent-queue
boot.user=> (.add concurrent-queue "example")
true
boot.user=> concurrent-queue
#object[java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue 0x750ee622 "[example]"]
```